# What are the steps to put your website under your own domain as opposed to a wordpress.com subdomain?

Tags: domains

I am very good in programming but never thought to create website with my own domain. I do not want to use something like

```
arshadblahblah.wordpress.com
```

I want to have my own domain e.g.

```
arshadblahblah.com
```

How should I proceed further? What are steps? What are the options?

Comment: What you are asking is very broad.   The answers you get will depend on what hosting company you choose, what content management system (CMS) you choose, which domain registrar you choose, and which DNS host you choose.   It sounds like you might be trying to use wordpress.com as your host.   If that is the case, we could answer that specifically.   Please edit your question to add more details about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

For the domain (arshadblahblah.com) you need a registrar. For the actual files, you need a host. Many companies offer both services. Different hosting companies have different options, different server types, etc. So it's good to know what your basic requirements are - do you want to code in Java? PHP? use a CMS like WordPress? Check with your CMS or programming language to determine what kind of server you'll need, and what type of database you may need.